# Area of ABC on a plane

Tags: 3d

[image]

In the above question could anyone please explain me what they have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry but I do not understand the suggested solution. 
Anyway, this is an alternative approach.

The cartesian equation of the plane $E$ is 
$$2x-y-2z+5=0$$
Therefore [the distance of $A$ from that plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_plane#Closest_point_and_distance_for_a_hyperplane_and_arbitrary_point) is
$$|AB|=\frac{|2(-4)-(2)-2(2)+5|}{\sqrt{2^2+(-1)^2+(-2)^2}}=3.$$
Moreover
$$|AC|=\|(-4-(-3),2-0,2-4)\|=\sqrt{1^2+2^2+(-2)^2}=3.$$
Now note that $AB \perp AC$, hence the required area is
$$\frac{|AB|\cdot|AC|}{2}=\frac{9}{2}.$$

Comment: How do you get the equation of a plane

Comment: And point B also ??

Comment: @koolman Let $ax+by+cz+d=0$ the equation of the plane then $(a,b,c)$ is parallel to the cross product of $(1,2,0)$ and $(1,0,1)$. Then find $d$ by imposing that the equation holds for $(-1,1,1)$.

Comment: @koolman You need not to find the coordinates of $B$. You need just the distance of $B$ from $A$.

Comment: And both AB and AC are perpendicular

Comment: @koolman $AB$ is orthogonal to the plane $E$ (minimum distance segment) and $AE$ is a parallel to that plane.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that

$$F:\;\;(-4,2,2)+\lambda(1,2,0)+\mu(1,0,1)$$

As $\;E,\,F\;$ are *parallel* planes, their distance $\;\mathcal D\;$ is the distance between any point in $\;E\;$ to the plane $\;F\;$, so:

$$\mathcal D^2=\min_{\lambda,\mu}d^2\left((-1,1,1)\,,\,\,(\lambda+\mu-4,\,2\lambda+2,\,\mu+2)\right)=$$

$$=\min\left[(\lambda+\mu-3)^2+(2\lambda+1)^2+(\mu+1)^2\right]=9\;\text{(why?)}$$

and thus the minimal distance is $\;3\;$

Since $\;||AB||\;$ is the above minimal distance and $\;C\;$ is on $\;F\;$ , the triangle $\;\Delta ABC\;$ is a straight angle one, with $\;\angle CAB=90^\circ\;$, and thus this triangle's area is simply

$$\frac{AC\cdot AB}2=\frac{3\cdot3}2=\frac92$$